# Polyline behind marker not working on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android development currently trying to build car tracking app. Car marker is on the current location and it will move along with polyline as i move. I have implemented everything but polyline is not drawing behind marker need some suggestions where i am making mistake. Thank you in advance!

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 0;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final String TAG = "";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private int markerCount;
    TextView locationText;
    String lat, longi, address1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map17);
        locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationText);
        markerCount = 0;

        //Check If Google Services Is Available
        if (getServicesAvailable()) {
            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Service Is Available!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Create The MapView Fragment
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        startTrackerService();

    }
    private void startTrackerService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, TrackerService.class));
    }
    /**
     * GOOGLE MAPS AND MAPS OBJECTS
     */

    // After Creating the Map Set Initial Location
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        //Uncomment To Show Google Location Blue Pointer
        // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    Marker mk = null;

    // Add A Map Pointer To The MAp
    public void addMarker(GoogleMap googleMap, double lat, double lon) {

        if (markerCount == 1) {
            animateMarker(mLastLocation, mk);
        } else if (markerCount == 0) {
            //Set Custom BitMap for Pointer
            int height = 80;
            int width = 45;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon_car);
            Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
            mMap = googleMap;

            LatLng latlong = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                    //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin3))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap((smallMarker))));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 16));

            //Set Marker Count to 1 after first marker is created
            markerCount = 1;

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                return;
            }
            //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public boolean getServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {

            Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Connect To Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * LOCATION LISTENER EVENTS
     */

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
//        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getServicesAvailable();

        // Resuming the periodic location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    //Method to display the location on UI
    private void displayLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            String location = String.valueOf(mLastLocation);
            Log.d("lat:", location);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {

                double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                String loc = "" + latitude + " ," + longitude + " ";
                Toast.makeText(this, loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Constants.lat1 = String.valueOf(latitude);
                Constants.lat2 = String.valueOf(longitude);
                Log.d("lat:", lat1);
                Log.d("lat:", lat2);
                //Add pointer to the map at location
                addMarker(mMap, latitude, longitude);

                try {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
                    locationText.setText(locationText.getText() + "\n" + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " +
                            addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
                    address1 = String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " +
                            addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));

                    Constants.address1 = address1;
                    Log.d("lat:", address1);


                   /* lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                    longi = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

                    Log.d("lat:",lat);
                    Log.d("lat:","true1");
                    Log.d("longi:", longi);
                    Log.d("lat:","true2");
                    Constants.lattitude = lat;
                    Log.d("lat:",Constants.lattitude);
                    Log.d("lat:","true3");
                    Constants.longitude = longi;
                    Log.d("longi:", Constants.longitude);
                    Log.d("lat:","true4");
*/


                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                new ReplyAsync(getApplicationContext(), new ReplyAsync.getReplyAsyncCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart(boolean status) {
                        Log.e("Result true", "Result true................");
                        //  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
//                progressDialog.setTitle(Constants.company_name);
                        //  progressDialog.setMessage(Constants.loadingMessage);
                        // progressDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(boolean result) {
                        if (result) {
                            Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Entered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("Result true", "Result true");
                        }
                    }
                }).execute(Constants.latlonginsertlink);


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    // Creating google api client object
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    //Creating location request object
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(AppConstants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(AppConstants.FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(AppConstants.DISPLACEMENT);
    }


    //Starting the location updates
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    //Stopping location updates
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }


    public static void animateMarker(final Location destination, final Marker marker) {
        if (marker != null) {
            final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();

            final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(1000); // duration 1 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, destination.getBearing()));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });

            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    private static float computeRotation(float fraction, float start, float end) {
        float normalizeEnd = end - start; // rotate start to 0
        float normalizedEndAbs = (normalizeEnd + 360) % 360;

        float direction = (normalizedEndAbs > 180) ? -1 : 1; // -1 = anticlockwise, 1 = clockwise
        float rotation;
        if (direction > 0) {
            rotation = normalizedEndAbs;
        } else {
            rotation = normalizedEndAbs - 360;
        }

        float result = fraction * rotation + start;
        return (result + 360) % 360;
    }

    private interface LatLngInterpolator {
        LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

        class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolator {
            @Override
            public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
                double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
                double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
                // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
                return new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        }
    }
}
```